# Rails: Spring permission error Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, permissions, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to set up a Ubuntu 14.04 box as a development environment for rails 4.2.

When I try to run `rails c`, I get the following error:

```
fileutils.rb:252:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /run/user/1000/spring (Errno::EACCES)
```

This is caused because `/run/user/1000` is owned by user `tyler` and I am trying to execute the commands as user `deployer`. I got there by logging into the system as `tyler` then `su - deployer`.

If I log into the system as `deployer`, I can execute `rails c` without issue and it creates a separate `/run/user/1001` directory owned by deployer.

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
- Rails-4.2.0
- ruby-2.2

Comment: Are you using Capistrano and run with rvm?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I'm using rbenv in a freshly created account with a new skeleton app build with rails-composer.

Answer (score 55):

It seems that the XDG_RUNTIME_DIR environment variable gets set for some reason. You can just run:

```
$ unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
$ rails c
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the 'deployer' user doesn't have permission to create directories within the 'tyler' user's home directory. This can be fixed by adding deployer user to the group tyler with

```
usermod -a -G tyler deployer
```

You'll probably want to run this command as root.

Answer (score 0):

If using VirtualBox / Vagrant, run the following:

```
sudo chown user:vagrant -R /run/user/1000
```

With user being your host username.

Answer (score 0):

This situation appears use rails with new user. So needs to be done give permission to deployer

```
sudo chown deployer -R /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but [RDP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30181641/10907864) above helped me to solve it.

**Just to add to his answer:**

After running the command below to fix the issue

```
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```

If you're in a production environment, run the command below to get into the rails console

```
rails c --environment=production
```

and if you're in a development environment, run the command below to get into the rails console

```
rails c
```

Or

```
rails c --environment=development
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**